# How to conditionally run jQuery based on server side decision

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to run a fadeIn when a C# object is not null.  I would imagine that the particulars shouldn't matter, but just in case its asp.net MVC 3 - razor.

jQuery

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MessageFadeIn(){
    $('messageLbl').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        //Animation complete
    });
}
</script>
```

ASP.NET

---

```
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
   //run jquery to fade this label in below...the label shouldnt display unless jQuery runs
   <label id="messageLbl" style="background-color:Red;color:White;">@ViewBag.Message</label>
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messageLbl only exists if they message is not null so it will work.

jQuery does not throw an error if you try to fadeIn on a non existant object. It just fails gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

In your HTML add CSS `display: none;` to the `style` attribute. That will make the `label` not displayed by default.

```
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
   //run jquery to fade this label in below...the label shouldnt display unless jQuery runs
   <label id="messageLbl" style="display: none; background-color:Red; color:White;">@ViewBag.Message</label>
}
```

and the jQuery (add `#` before `messageLbl` to indicate it's an [ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function {
    $('#messageLbl').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        //Animation complete
    });
});
</script>
```

As **@Raynos** correctly explained, there will no problem if `#messageLbl` does not exist in the document.

A [little jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3wzz/) to demonstrate how it works.